# c3po helper threads to be deadlocking

Tags: java, database, derby, c3p0

I used c3po pooling with my gui application. I have the following configuration

```
overrides.put("maxStatementsPerConnection", 30);
overrides.put("maxPoolSize",70); 
overrides.put("checkoutTimeout", 50000);
```

Occasionally I get into a situation where an attempt to get a connection times out

```
java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:65)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:527)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at com.jthink.jaikoz.db.Db.createConnection(Db.java:402)
```

Even though I'm sure I have no other connections open. In fact I did used to have some additional options enabled (`debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces`, `unreturnedConnectionTimeout`) to try and identify problems with not closing connections and found no problems. This problem rarely occurs and only happens after running it for some time. I'm using with an embedded `Derby` database.

As luck would have it when it failed this time I was running it with it `Yourkit` Profiler enabled, and I could do monitor profiling , and found that we have three c3po threads all waiting on each other, which is why I think there is actually a deadlock here

```
com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread#0
com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread#1
com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread#2
```

Is this analogous to the setting of `numHelperThreads` ?

I took a screendump of this

[image]

Have I found a problem with c3po, can I code to recover from it ?

Comment: Sorry but what is c3po? Other then the robot in starwars?

Comment: @Iznogood c3p0 is a PooledConnection library: http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html

Comment: just to be clear, what version of c3p0 are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

The three threads you see are indeed the helper threads. These do slow JDBC operations asynchronously, eg closing unused connections. The last line of the stacktrace

```
com.jthink.jaikoz.db.Db.createConnection(Db.java:402)
```

seems to indicate that C3P0 is trying to open a new connection, but the database refuses to create one. I assume the 'Jaikoz' database is refusing the connection, the C3P0 connection pool is not the issue here.

Simon